# Creating a flow from actor in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

It's possible to create sources and sinks from actors using `Source.actorPublisher()` and `Sink.actorSubscriber()` methods respectively. But is it possible to create a `Flow` from actor?

Conceptually there doesn't seem to be a good reason not to, given that it implements both `ActorPublisher` and `ActorSubscriber` traits, but unfortunately, the `Flow` object doesn't have any method for doing this. In [this](http://bryangilbert.com/blog/2015/02/04/akka-reactive-streams/) excellent blog post it's done in an earlier version of Akka Streams, so the question is if it's possible also in the latest (2.4.9) version.

Comment: Hmmm... I would suggest to give it a try and if it does not work, then update your question.

Comment: There's no way to do it. Maybe I wasn't clear, but a quick look in `Flow` object's methods reveals that there's no such method. My question is if it exists in another form/API. Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm part of the Akka team and would like to use this question to clarify a few things about the raw Reactive Streams interfaces. I hope you'll find this useful.

Most notably, we'll be posting multiple posts on the Akka team blog about building custom stages, including Flows, soon, so keep an eye on it.

**Don't use ActorPublisher / ActorSubscriber**

Please don't use `ActorPublisher` and `ActorSubscriber`. They're too low level and you might end up implementing them in such a way that's violating the [Reactive Streams specification](http://www.reactive-streams.org/). They're a relict of the past and even then were only "power-user mode only". There really is no reason to use those classes nowadays. We never provided a way to build a flow because the complexity is simply explosive if it was exposed as "raw" Actor API for you to implement and get [all the rules implemented correctly](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm).

If you really really want to implement raw ReactiveStreams interfaces, then please do use the [Specification's TCK](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/tree/master/tck) to verify your implementation is correct. You will likely be caught off guard by some of the more complex corner cases a `Flow` (or in RS terminology a `Processor` has to handle).

**Most operations are possible to build without going low-level**

Many flows you should be able to simply build by building from a `Flow[T]` and adding the needed operations onto it, just as an example:

```
val newFlow: Flow[String, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[String].map(_.toInt)
```

Which is a reusable description of the Flow.

Since you're asking about power user mode, this is the most powerful operator on the DSL itself: `statefulFlatMapConcat`. The vast majority of operations operating on plain stream elements is expressable using it: `Flow.statefulMapConcat[T](f: () ⇒ (Out) ⇒ Iterable[T]): Repr[T]`.

If you need timers you could `zip` with a `Source.timer` etc.

**GraphStage is *the* simplest and *safest* API to build custom stages**

Instead, building Sources/Flows/Sinks has its own powerful *and safe* API: the `GraphStage`. Please read the [documentation about building custom GraphStages](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-customize.html#graphstage-scala) (they can be a Sink/Source/Flow or even *any* arbitrary shape). It handles all of the complex Reactive Streams rules for you, while giving you full freedom and type-safety while implementing your stages (which could be a Flow).

For example, taken from the docs, is an GraphStage implementation of the `filter(T => Boolean)` operator:

```
class Filter[A](p: A => Boolean) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[A, A]] {

  val in = Inlet[A]("Filter.in")
  val out = Outlet[A]("Filter.out")

  val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          val elem = grab(in)
          if (p(elem)) push(out, elem)
          else pull(in)
        }
      })
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          pull(in)
        }
      })
    }
}
```

It also handles asynchronous channels and is fusable by default.

In addition to the docs, these blog posts explain in detail why this API is the holy grail of building custom stages of any shape:

- [Akka team blog: Mastering GraphStages (part 1, introduction)](http://blog.akka.io/streams/2016/07/30/mastering-graph-stage-part-1) - a high level overview
- ... tomorrow we'll publish one about it's API as well...
- [Kunicki blog: Implementing a Custom Akka Streams Graph Stage](http://blog.kunicki.org/blog/2016/07/20/implementing-a-custom-akka-streams-graph-stage/) - another example implementing sources (really applies 1:1 to building Flows)

Comment: Does the recommendation_"don't use ActorPublisher and ActorSubscriber. .. violating the Reactive Streams specification"_ is meant to apply to _"create a Flow from actor?"_ or also for creating a source from an Actor.                                            Because actors seems to be a natural way to create sources: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#actorPublisher. Still, wondering if the out of the box implementation for this is smart to not overwhelm the actor?. See below for "actor contain a buffer ."

Comment: Just use a GraphStage to implement your source, it'll be faster and more performant ;-) Linking to the single method Akka Streams has to bridge those directly is a bit misleading, since we have a full page explaining how to implement custom stages: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-customize.html As I already mentioned, sticking to GraphStage will give a lot of benefits: performance, fusability, debuggability etc. If you already have a publisher, you can just use it with Akka though, sure.

Answer (score 20):

Konrad's solution demonstrates how to create a custom stage that utilizes Actors, but in most cases I think that is a bit overkill.

Usually you have some Actor that is capable of responding to questions:

```
val actorRef : ActorRef = ???

type Input = ???
type Output = ???

val queryActor : Input => Future[Output] = 
  (actorRef ? _) andThen (_.mapTo[Output])
```

This can be easily utilized with basic [`Flow`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/?_ga=1.42089507.723935664.1469018756#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow) functionality which takes in the maximum number of concurrent requests:

```
val actorQueryFlow : Int => Flow[Input, Output, _] =
  (parallelism) => Flow[Input].mapAsync[Output](parallelism)(queryActor)
```

Now `actorQueryFlow` can be integrated into any stream...

Comment: I actually agree, should find time to amend my answer... feel free to edit it if you have the time! Both ways should be explained, yours as the recommended one

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski I appreciate you verifying my answer.  Also, thanks for all the work on akka.  You guys are doing some really cool stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution build by using a graph stage. The actor has to acknowledge all messages in order to have back-pressure. The actor is notified when the stream fails/completes and the stream fails when the actor terminates.
This can be useful if you don't want to use ask, e.g. when not every input message has a corresponding output message.

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, Status, Terminated}
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.stage.{GraphStage, GraphStageLogic, InHandler, OutHandler}

object ActorRefBackpressureFlowStage {
  case object StreamInit
  case object StreamAck
  case object StreamCompleted
  case class StreamFailed(ex: Throwable)
  case class StreamElementIn[A](element: A)
  case class StreamElementOut[A](element: A)
}

/**
  * Sends the elements of the stream to the given `ActorRef` that sends back back-pressure signal.
  * First element is always `StreamInit`, then stream is waiting for acknowledgement message
  * `ackMessage` from the given actor which means that it is ready to process
  * elements. It also requires `ackMessage` message after each stream element
  * to make backpressure work. Stream elements are wrapped inside `StreamElementIn(elem)` messages.
  *
  * The target actor can emit elements at any time by sending a `StreamElementOut(elem)` message, which will
  * be emitted downstream when there is demand.
  *
  * If the target actor terminates the stage will fail with a WatchedActorTerminatedException.
  * When the stream is completed successfully a `StreamCompleted` message
  * will be sent to the destination actor.
  * When the stream is completed with failure a `StreamFailed(ex)` message will be send to the destination actor.
  */
class ActorRefBackpressureFlowStage[In, Out](private val flowActor: ActorRef) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[In, Out]] {

  import ActorRefBackpressureFlowStage._

  val in: Inlet[In] = Inlet("ActorFlowIn")
  val out: Outlet[Out] = Outlet("ActorFlowOut")

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

    private lazy val self = getStageActor {
      case (_, StreamAck) =>
        if(firstPullReceived) {
          if (!isClosed(in) && !hasBeenPulled(in)) {
            pull(in)
          }
        } else {
          pullOnFirstPullReceived = true
        }

      case (_, StreamElementOut(elemOut)) =>
        val elem = elemOut.asInstanceOf[Out]
        emit(out, elem)

      case (_, Terminated(targetRef)) =>
        failStage(new WatchedActorTerminatedException("ActorRefBackpressureFlowStage", targetRef))

      case (actorRef, unexpected) =>
        failStage(new IllegalStateException(s"Unexpected message: `$unexpected` received from actor `$actorRef`."))
    }
    var firstPullReceived: Boolean = false
    var pullOnFirstPullReceived: Boolean = false

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
      //initialize stage actor and watch flow actor.
      self.watch(flowActor)
      tellFlowActor(StreamInit)
    }

    setHandler(in, new InHandler {

      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        val elementIn = grab(in)
        tellFlowActor(StreamElementIn(elementIn))
      }

      override def onUpstreamFailure(ex: Throwable): Unit = {
        tellFlowActor(StreamFailed(ex))
        super.onUpstreamFailure(ex)
      }

      override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        tellFlowActor(StreamCompleted)
        super.onUpstreamFinish()
      }
    })

    setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        if(!firstPullReceived) {
          firstPullReceived = true
          if(pullOnFirstPullReceived) {
            if (!isClosed(in) && !hasBeenPulled(in)) {
              pull(in)
            }
          }
        }

      }

      override def onDownstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        tellFlowActor(StreamCompleted)
        super.onDownstreamFinish()
      }
    })

    private def tellFlowActor(message: Any): Unit = {
      flowActor.tell(message, self.ref)
    }

  }

  override def shape: FlowShape[In, Out] = FlowShape(in, out)

}
```