# How to subscribe websockets to actor's messages using Akka Streams and Akka HTTP?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I want to send notifications to clients via websockets. This notifications are generated by actors, hence I'm trying to create a stream of actor's messages at server startup and subscribe websockects connections to this stream (sending only those notifications emitted since subscription)

With [Source.actorRef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33415214/3517383) we can create a Source of actor messages.

```
val ref = Source.actorRef[Weather](Int.MaxValue, fail)
                .filter(!_.raining)
                .to(Sink foreach println )
                .run()

ref ! Weather("02139", 32.0, true)
```

But how can I subscribe (akka http*) websockets connections to this source if has been materialized already?

*WebSockets connections in Akka HTTP requires a Flow[Message, Message, Any]

What I'm trying to do is something like

```
// at server startup
val notifications: Source[Notification,ActorRef] = Source.actorRef[Notificacion](5,OverflowStrategy.fail)
val ref = notifications.to(Sink.foreach(println(_))).run()
val notificationActor = system.actorOf(NotificationActor.props(ref))

// on ws connection
val notificationsWS = path("notificationsWS") {
  parameter('name) { name ⇒
    get {
      onComplete(flow(name)){
        case Success(f) => handleWebSocketMessages(f)
        case Failure(e) => throw e
      }
    }
  }
}

def flow(name: String) = {
  val messages = notifications filter { n => n.name equals name } map { n => TextMessage.Strict(n.data) }
  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, notifications)
}
```

This doensn't work because the notifications source is not the one that is materialized, hence it doens't emit any element.

Note: I was using Source.actorPublisher and it was working but ktoso [discourages his usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39132662/3517383) and also I was getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: onNext is not allowed when the stream has not requested elements, totalDemand was 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the materialised `actorRef` to some external router actor using `mapMaterializedValue`.

```
Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(Sink.ignore, notifications)(Keep.right)
  .mapMaterializedValue(srcRef => router ! srcRef)
```

The router can keep track of your sources actorrefs (deathwatch can help tidying things up) and forward messages to them.

NB: you're probably already aware, but note that by using `Source.actorRef` to feed your flow, your flow will not be backpressure aware (with the strategy you chose it will just crash under load).