# Akka streams - can it be scale like regular actors or other way?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I'm having a code that executing a pipeline using Akka streams.

My question is what is the best way of scale it out? Can it be done using Akka streams also?

Or it need to be converted into actors/other way?

The code snippet is:

```
val future = SqsSource(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient)
.takeWhile(_=>true)
.map { m: Message =>
(m, Ack())
}.runWith(SqsAckSink(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your code a bit then your stream will be materialized into multiple `Actor` values.  These materialized Actors will get you the concurrency you are looking for:

```
val future = 
  SqsSource(sqsEnpoint)(awsSqsClient)           //Actor 1
    .via(Flow[Message] map (m => (m, Ack())))   //Actor 2
    .to(SqsAckSink(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient))  //Actor 3
    .run()
```

Note the use of `via` and `to`.  These are important because they indicate that those stages of the stream should be materialized into separate Actors.  In your example code you are using `map` and `runWith` on the `Source` which would result in only 1 Actor being created because of [operator fusion](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#operator-fusion).

**Flows that Ask External Actors**

If you're looking to extend to even more Actors then you can use `Flow#mapAsync` to query an external Actor to do more work, similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125760/creating-a-flow-from-actor-in-akka-streams/39250275#39250275).

Comment: so does it means that the max degree of parallizem is 3? can it be more?

Comment: @john Updated answer to reflect more async capabilities.