# [Scala, Akka]: Future onComplete does not execute outside the sender

Tags: promise, akka, future, akka-http

I have a routes class (sender), an actor and a helper class. From the routes class, I send a request to the actor and get a Future response. Now, I want to pass the future response to the helper and resolve it there.

TestRoute.scala:

```
val response: Future[Any] = (actor ? request) (timeout)
handler(response)(executionContext)
```

TestHelper.scala:

```
def handler(futureResponse: Future[Any])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): StandardRoute = {
  onComplete(futureResponse) {
    case Success(s) => complete(s)
    case Failure(f) => reject
   }
}
```

The problem is that while `onComplete` works from within `TestRoute.scala`, it does not work when moved to `TestHelper.scala`. Any ideas what the problem might be?

EDIT: By "it does not work', I mean that the entire onComplete function is skipped over and not executed at all - no errors, just skips over.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: Your question needs more context. From what I can tell, your handler function should either return a new Future[StandardRoute] or Unit if it's side-effecting.

Comment: The code looks roughly OK to me, how are you exercising it when you say it is "just skipped over"? Have you tried adding print/log statements to make sure neither case is evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

There are few "oddities" with your code that **may** explain the issue.

1.I am surprised that your code even compiles given that `futureResponse` is of type `Future[Any]`.  [You should use `mapTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125760/creating-a-flow-from-actor-in-akka-streams/39250275#39250275) to convert the `Any` to a known type `T`.  The way you have the code constructed now implies that there is a Marshaller for `Any` which may be available in `TestRoute` but not in `TestHelper`.

2.The fact that `response` is a `val` and not a `def` means that the `Actor` will only be queried once, instead of once per request.  I think you want something like:

```
type Output = ???

val response: () => Future[Output] = 
  () => (actor ? request) (timeout) andThen (_.mapTo[Output])
```

Which would change the signature of handler:

```
def handler(futureResponse: () => Future[Output])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): StandardRoute = 
  onComplete(futureResponse()) {
    case Success(s) => complete(s)
    case Failure(f) => reject
  }
```